How to skip to most recent sample when viewing atop log file
I recently discovered atop. I've set it to save logs via systemctl restart atop.service.
I love reviewing past logs with atop -r <PATH_TO_LOGFILE> and moving forwards/backwards in time with t/T.
When I run this command, atop always starts at the beginning of the logfile (the oldest sample). When I want to review recent history, however, I would like to see the most recent samples first.
I've read through the man page but couldn't find such a command. There is r to go back to the beginning. But conspicuously missing is the inverse (I tried R but that enables PSIZE gathering).
A workaround is to go to a specific time by pressing b and entering the current timestamp. But that's tedious. Is there something better that I'm missing?
